# Numpy: crop object of interest by removing x and y axis that are black

Tags: python, numpy

Problem: I have some images (in numpy) that have a black background. In the middle, I have an object that I am interested in. I would like to crop the object of interest, in a numpy way.

Lets say we have an image that looks like this:

[image: a generated image for demo and testing]

I need a function `crop_region_of_interest`, that detects and removes any X and Y axis if the entire axis is black or [0,0,0], in order to get this:

[image]

Some codes used in this demo:

```
# just a function to add colors to generate test image
def add_color(img, pixel_x, pixel_y, rgb):
    img[pixel_x][pixel_y][0] = rgb[0]
    img[pixel_x][pixel_y][1] = rgb[1]
    img[pixel_x][pixel_y][2] = rgb[2]

def generate_fake_image_for_stackoverflow():
    # a black background image
    base_img = np.zeros((16,16,3), dtype=int)

    # lets add some colors, these are the region we want
    for x in range(4,10):
        for y in range(6,12):
            if(x==y):
                continue
            if(x+y<12):
                continue
            if(x+y>16):
                continue
            add_color(base_img, x,y, [255,60,90])

    return base_img

# a hardcoded cropped to generate expected result 
def crop_region_of_interest(img):
    # crop first axis
    cropped = img[4:10]

    # transpose to second axis, so can crop
    cropped = cropped.transpose((1,0,2))
    cropped = cropped[6:12]

    # transpose back
    cropped = cropped.transpose((1,0,2))
    cropped = cropped.transpose((1,0,2))
    cropped = cropped.transpose((1,0,2))

    return cropped

img = generate_fake_image_for_stackoverflow() # to generate a test image
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

cropped = crop_region_of_interest(img) # a hardcoded cropped to generate expected result, this to be replaced 
plt.imshow(cropped)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Seems relevant - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132914/crop-black-border-of-image-using-numpy

Comment: If I'm understanding the algorithm correctly, the top answer there would also remove blank rows and columns from the middle of the image, not just the edges. But this can probably be addressed using `min` and `max` on the resulting indices... hmm.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Think you can read up on `II. Crop while keeping the inner all black rows or columns` section in the accepted answer there.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. This might be a duplicate, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just slight edit on the solution provided by [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132914/crop-black-border-of-image-using-numpy]

```
def crop_image(img,tol=0):
    # img is 2D or 3D image data
    # tol  is tolerance
    mask = img>tol
    if img.ndim==3:
        mask = mask.all(2)
    m,n = mask.shape
    mask0,mask1 = mask.any(0),mask.any(1)
    col_start,col_end = mask0.argmax(),n-mask0[::-1].argmax()
    row_start,row_end = mask1.argmax(),m-mask1[::-1].argmax()
    return img[row_start:row_end,col_start:col_end]
```

Thanks @jamal and @divakar

Answer (score 2):

I thought about it some more, following @Divakar's comment suggestion. The process is fairly tricky, so I refactored it into *very* short functions so as to give everything a useful name.

```
def bounds(values):
    # create a slice object representing the range from lowest to highest
    # index value. Add 1 on the high side because of how ranges work
    return slice(min(values), max(values) + 1)

def crop_bounds(mask, axis):
    # find the indexes along this axis where any of the pixels are
    # non-black, then convert those indexes into a bounds slice.
    return bounds(np.where(mask.any(axis)))

def trim(img):
    # True where pixels are non-black.
    mask = np.any(img != 0, axis = 2)
    # Get the crop bounds for each axis, and slice with them.
    return img[crop_bounds(mask, 0)][crop_bounds(mask, 1)]
```

(Slice objects are a Python built-in, supported by Numpy. They basically represent the values used in a slicing operation; `x[slice(a,b)]` is equivalent to `x[a:b]`.)

Comment: having error: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: In this case, please ask a new question and include a complete, reproducible example, including making it clear how the image data is represented.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function :

```py
def crop_image(img):
    x_dim = len(img)
    y_dim = len(img[0])

    vertical_bounds = []
    horizontal_bounds = []

    for index_x, line in enumerate(img):
        for index_y, value in enumerate(line):

            if value[0]+value[1]+value[2] != 0:
                vertical_bounds.append(index_x)
                horizontal_bounds.append(index_y)

    cropped = img[min(vertical_bounds):max(vertical_bounds)+1]

    cropped = cropped.transpose((1,0,2))    
    cropped = cropped[min(horizontal_bounds):max(horizontal_bounds)+1]

    cropped = cropped.transpose((1,0,2))
    cropped = cropped.transpose((1,0,2))
    cropped = cropped.transpose((1,0,2))
    return cropped
```

Comment: It's better to use numpy tools to process numpy arrays where possible.

Comment: trying to humbly contribute, i confess my ignorance of numpy build in tools. But i will definitely keep an eye on the other submitted solutions in order to learn about a more numpyesque solution.

Comment: i have tested, your code works, but its slower than @Divakar suggested [https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/132914/crop-black-border-of-image-using-numpy]